# Semtech LR1110 GPS coordinates from GNSS

Tags: gps

I am thinking of using [Semtech LR1110](https://www.semtech.com/products/wireless-rf/lora-transceivers/lr1110) for designing tracking device in field with LoRa. Since this one has GNSS & LoRa on SoC, so going with LR1110.

But I have a concerns about LR1110.

1. How can I use GNSS data to get accurate GPS location ?
   Is there any open source (free) way to get GPS coordinates from GNSS data ?